# Number Guessing game Computer Playing

Tags: python-3.x

I have created this game. User is giving a number from 1 to 100. Computer is trying to guess it. User is giving hint to computer to go lower or go higher. I am open for any feedback.

Thank you in advance.

```
import os
import random
os.system('clear')

user = int(input("Please enter a number between 1-100: "))
print("Your Number is: " + str(user))

comp_list = list(range(1,101))
comp_selection = random.choice(comp_list)
count = 0
def game(num, a = 1, b = 100):
    global count
    print("I have chosen " + str(num) + "\nShould I go Higher or Lower or Correct? ")
    user = input("Your Selection: ")
    if user == "L":
        count = count + 1
        low_game(a, num)
    elif user == "H":
        count = count + 1
        high_game(num, b)
    else:
        print("I have guessed correctly in " + str(count) + " tries")


def low_game(old_low, new_High):
   
    x = new_High
    new_comp_list = list(range(old_low, x))
    new_comp_selection = random.choice(new_comp_list)   
    game(new_comp_selection, old_low, x)

def high_game(new_low, old_high):

    x = new_low + 1
    new_comp_list = list(range(x, old_high))
    new_comp_selection = random.choice(new_comp_list)   
    game(new_comp_selection,x, old_high)

game(comp_selection)
```

Comment: You never change the `game_list`.  Just add a `print` in `game` and see.  Also calling functions as if they are a "goto" that will never return back to the calling point is not the way to code this.  Just track the high and low range values and use `random.randint` to choose and use a while loop until the right value is chosen.  `user_answer.upper()` also has no effect.  It *returns* the uppercase value, but does not modify `user_answer`.  Learn to use a debugger to step through your code and watch the flow of code and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, you have over complicated the game with recursive functons.
Here is a much simplified game with penalties for player who does not answer correctly
or falsifies the answer:)

```py
import sys, random

wins = 0
loss = 0

while 1:
    user = input('Please enter a number between 1-100: (return or x = quit) > ' )
    if user in [ '', 'x' ]:
        break
    elif user.isnumeric():
        user = int( user )
        if user < 1 or user > 100:
            sys.stdout.write( 'Number must be between 1 and 100!!\n' )
        else:
            low, high, count = 1, 100, 0
            while 1:
                p = random.randint( low, high )
                count += 1
                while 1:
                    answer = input( f'Is your number {p}? Y/N > ').upper()
                    if answer in [ 'Y','N' ]:
                        break
                    else:
                        sys.stderr.write( 'Answer must be Y or N\n' )
                if answer == 'N':
                    if p != user:
                        if input( f'Is my number (H)igher or (L)ower? > ').upper() == 'H':
                            if user < p:
                                high = p - 1
                            else:
                                sys.stderr.write( f'Wrong!! Your number was lower. You loss\n' )
                                loss =+ 1
                                break
                        else:
                            if user > p:
                                low = p + 1
                            else:
                                sys.stderr.write( f'Wrong!! Your number higher. You loss\n' )
                                loss =+ 1
                                break
                    else:
                        sys.stderr.write( f'Cheat!! Your number is {user}!! You loss\n')
                        loss =+ 1
                        break
                else:
                    if user == p:
                        sys.stdout.write( f'I guessed Correctly in {count} guesses\n' )
                        wins += 1
                    else:
                        sys.stderr.write( f'Cheat!! This is not your number. You loss\n' )
                        loss =+ 1
                    break

print( f'Computer won = {wins}  :  You lost = {loss}' )
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have really overly complicated the problem.  The basic process flow is to have the computer guess a number within a fixed range of possible numbers.  If the guess is incorrect, the user tells the computer how to adjust the list by either taking the guessed number as the low end or the high end of the guessing range.  So to accomplish this, I would do the following:

```
from random import randint  

# Function to request input and verify input type is valid
def getInput(prompt, respType= None):
    while True:
        resp = input(prompt)
        if respType == str or respType == None:
            break
        else:
            try:
                resp = respType(resp)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input, please try again')
    return resp  

def GuessingGame():
    MAX_GUESSES = 10  # Arbritray Fixed Number of Guesses
    # The Game Preamble
    print('Welcome to the Game\nIn this game you will be asked to provide a number between 1 and 100 inclusive')
    print('The Computer will attempt to guess your number in ten or fewer guesses, for each guess you will respond by telling the computer: ')
    print('either:\n  High - indicating the computer should guess higher\n  Low - indicating the computer should guess lower, or')
    print('  Yes - indicating the computer guessed correctly.')
    
    # The Game
    resp = getInput('Would You Like To Play?, Respond Yes/No ')
    while True: 
        secret_number = None
        if resp.lower()[0] == 'n':
            return   
        guess_count = 0
        guess_range = [0, 100]
        secret_number = getInput('Enter an Integer between 1 and 100 inclusive', respType= int)
        print(f'Your secret number is {secret_number}')
        while guess_count <= MAX_GUESSES:
            guess = randint(guess_range[0], guess_range[1]+1)
            guess_count += 1
            resp =getInput(f'The computer Guesses {guess} is this correct? (High?Low/Yes) ')
            if resp.lower()[0] == 'y':
                break
            else:
                if resp.lower()[0] == 'l':
                    guess_range[1] = guess - 1
                else:
                    guess_range[0] = guess + 1
                    
        if  guess == secret_number:
            print (f'The Computer has Won by Guessing your secret number {secret_number}')
        else:
            print(f'The Computer failed to guess your secret number {secret_number}')
        resp = getInput('Would You Like To Play Again?, Respond Yes/No ')
```

Comment: Please have the curtesy of recognizing the work submitted by either myself or @Derek by  checking the mark on left side of post.